# focus for java applets

Tags: java, applet, jframe, jpanel

I made a java game that is all based on JPanel.  When I add it to a JFrame it works perfectly, and when I add it to a JApplet and test it with the built in applet tester of eclipse it works perfectly.  However, when I try to run the applet through an html site it doesn't work.  It loads, but it doesn't take keyboard input.  I have it set up where "pressing s" starts the game, but even when I click on the game and press s, nothing happens.

Do I have to set the keyboard focus, because I thought that was done automatically.

Comment: What browser on what platform are you using? Have you tested other applets that use the keyboard to rule out a problem with your browser? (You can try http://xenomachina.com/soko/ which uses the keyboard, but is based on AWT not Swing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it doesn't take keyboard input.

KeyEvents are only passed to the component that has focus. I would guess your panel doesn't have focus, so make sure you make the panel focusable and then use the requestFocusInWindow() method once the GUI is visible to make sure the panel has focus.

However, the better solution to the problem is not to rely on the KeyListener but instead to use Key Bindings. Swing was designed to use Key Bindings.

Read more about [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/).

Comment: Calling requestFocusInWindow() in the class that extends JApplet after I added the panel to the applet worked.  thank you very much.

Comment: Also, I will definitely consider using key bindings over key listeners in the future.

Comment: @Jeff, then why haven't you accepted the answer yet? I knew I should only have mentioned the Key Bindings approach. Too many begineers take the perceived easy way out.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't accepted your answer yet because this was my first post on stackoverflow and I didn't know.  And I am not going to rewrite my code to use key bindings over listeners because I was only designing this game as a first step, and I plan to move on after it.  I don't want to waste time reworking something that already works.